# Rails Many-to-many relationship with extension generating incorrect SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, relational-database

I'm having an issue where a many-to-many relationship with an "extension" is generating incorrect SQL.

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: :User
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items_bought,
    -> { joins(:order).where.not(orders: { state: :expired }).order(created_at: :desc) },
    foreign_key: :buyer_id,
    class_name: :OrderItem

  has_many :videos_bought,
    -> { joins(:orders).select('DISTINCT ON (videos.id) videos.*').reorder('videos.id DESC') },
    through: :order_items_bought,
    source: :item,
    source_type: :Video do
      def confirmed
        where(orders: { state: :confirmed })
      end
    end
end
```

`user.videos_bought.confirmed` generates this SQL:

```
Video Load (47.0ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT ON (videos.id) videos.* FROM 
"videos" INNER JOIN "order_items" "order_items_videos_join" ON 
"order_items_videos_join"."item_id" = "videos"."id" AND 
"order_items_videos_join"."item_type" = $1 INNER JOIN 
"orders" ON "orders"."id" = "order_items_videos_join"."order_id" INNER JOIN 
"order_items" ON "videos"."id" = "order_items"."item_id" WHERE 
"order_items"."buyer_id" = $2 AND ("orders"."state" != $3) AND "order_items"."item_type" = $4 AND 
"orders"."state" = $5 ORDER BY videos.id DESC, "order_items"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $6
```

Which returns some `Video` records which are joined with orders that do NOT have state confirmed. I would expect all orders to have state confirmed.

If I use raw SQL everything works fine:

```
has_many :videos_bought,
  -> {
    joins('INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id = order_items.order_id')
      .select('DISTINCT ON (videos.id) videos.*')
      .reorder('videos.id DESC')
  },
  through: :order_items_bought,
  source: :item,
  source_type: :Video do
    def confirmed
      where(orders: { state: :confirmed })
    end
end
```

Now `user.videos_bought.confirmed` generates this SQL:

```
Video Load (5.4ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT ON (videos.id) videos.* FROM 
"videos" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON 
"videos"."id" = "order_items"."item_id" INNER JOIN orders ON 
orders.id = order_items.order_id WHERE 
"order_items"."buyer_id" = $1 AND ("orders"."state" != $2) AND
"order_items"."item_type" = $3 AND "orders"."state" = $4 ORDER BY
videos.id DESC, "order_items"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $5
```

Which seems more succinct because it avoids the auto generated `order_items_videos_join` name. It also only returns orders that have state confirmed.

Any idea what is going on? Does ActiveRecord just generate faulty SQL sometimes?

Using rails `5.1.5`. Upgrading to latest made no difference.

I'm hoping to get an explanation on why Rails generates the `order_items_videos_join` string in the first case but not in the second case. Also, why the second SQL query produces incorrect results. I can edit the question with more code and data samples if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not just generate faulty SQL sometimes, but there's a little nuance to it such that starting simple is best when it comes to defining relationships.  For example, let's rework your queries to get that `DISTINCT ON` out of there.  I've never seen a need to use that SQL clause.

Before chaining highly customized association logic, let's just see if there's simpler way to query first, and then check to see whether there's a strong case for turning your queries into associations.

**Looks like you've got a schema like this:**

User

- id

Order

- id
- state

OrderItem

- id
- order_id
- buyer_id (any reason this is on OrderItem and not on Order?)
- item_type   (Video)
- item_id     (videos.id)

Video

- id

**A couple of tidbits**

- No need to create association extensions for query conditions that would make perfectly good scopes on the model.  See below.

A perfectly good query might look like

```
Video.joins(order_item: :order).
    where(order_items: {
       buyer_id: 123, 
       order: {
          state: 'confirmed'
       }).
    # The following was part of the initial logic but
    #   doesn't alter the query results.
    # where.not(order_items: {
    #    order: {state: 'expired'}
    # }).
    order('id desc')
```

Here's another way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items, foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  def videos_purchased
    Video.where(id: order_items.videos.confirmed.pluck(:id))
  end
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
  scope :bought, -> {where.not(orders: {state: 'cancelled'})}
  scope :videos, -> {where(item_type: 'Video')}
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items, ...

  scope :confirmed, -> {where(orders: {state: 'confirmed'})}
end

...
user = User.first()
user.videos_purchased
```

I might have the syntax a little screwy when it comes to table and attribute names, but this should be a start.

Notice that I changed it from one to two queries.  I suggest running with that until you really notice that you have a performance problem, and even then you might have an easier time just caching queries, than trying to optimize complex join logic.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! The reason for the `DISTINCT ON` was to ensure `videos_purchased` only contains unique items and not duplicates. I guess you work around that by using a second query?

I have buyer_id on both Order and OrderItem in order to make `order_items_bought` work with `foreign_key`.

The main thing I was curious about was why does Rails generate the `order_items_videos_join` string in my first example. That's what seems to throw off the query.

Comment: `order_items_videos_join` is an alias for the `order_items` table.  The way the sql is generated, you'll notice that there are two joins on order_item.

Comment: Since you are using rails 5 you can use  `left_outer_joins ` instead of  `.select('DISTINCT ON (videos.id) videos.*') `